# convert column decimal to binary by bash AWK

Tags: awk

Input.txt

```
09/07/2021 11:08:39.591451 12606 4456531
09/07/2021 11:08:43.801062 12350 4456531
09/07/2021 11:08:49.207881 14398 4472899
09/07/2021 11:08:51.944042 14350 4210691
```

expected output.txt

```
09/07/2021 11:08:39.591451  11000100111110  10001000000000001010011
09/07/2021 11:08:43.801062  11000000111110  10001000000000001010011
09/07/2021 11:08:49.207881  11100000111110  10001000100000001000011
09/07/2021 11:08:51.944042  11100000001110  10000000100000000000011
```

I want to use bash AWK to convert column3 & column4 decimal to binary numbers. I have tried bash "while read loop" BUT the performance is too low while working on 100k lines huge file. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Add your code to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55240921/3776858) `print d2b($0)` with `$3=d2b($3); $4=d2b($4); print`.

Comment: Short, sweet and right on the money. Great link!

Comment: perfect! 100k lines took 13 sec which is much more efficient. Thank you @Cyrus !!

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing if the version at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68511113/1745001 runs any faster or slower if you wouldn't mind trying it. If so please post 3rd-run timings for both solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Or with `dc`:

```
paste -d' ' <(<infile cut -d' ' -f1,2)                                \
            <(<infile (echo 2o; cut -d' ' -f3 | sed 's/$/p/'; ) | dc) \
            <(<infile (echo 2o; cut -d' ' -f4 | sed 's/$/p/'; ) | dc)
```

Output:

```
09/07/2021 11:08:39.591451 11000100111110 10001000000000001010011
09/07/2021 11:08:43.801062 11000000111110 10001000000000001010011
09/07/2021 11:08:49.207881 11100000111110 10001000100000001000011
09/07/2021 11:08:51.944042 11100000001110 10000000100000000000011
```

Comment: While the performance will not match `awk` -- definitely worth the vote for example with rarely used `dc` `:)`